# Coinbase API price subscription(Buy,Sell,Spot)

Tags: coinbase-api

Is there a way to subscribe to real time bitcoin prices  using CoinBase Api.

Ideally: "Buy Price", "Sell Price", "Spot Price" and if anytime any of these change there is some sort of a callback.

Currently, I am not looking at polling at fixed interval.

I was looking at the .Net version of the API: https://github.com/bchavez/Coinbase

Comment: There is a way of course - what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Simone, I was looking at the .Net version of the lib, and did not seem obvious to me that there was a subscription model. From you comment it seems to me its my lack of knowledge on my end so will read up more. thank you.